# Systemctl service with variables show empty

Tags: bash, systemctl

When VM is created, a systemctl service is installed (script1.sh) runs, then later (script2.sh) runs, but variables in service are not updated.

**Background**

I have a `systemctl` service which is defined when VM is created. (script1.sh)
Later I collect variables values that I would pass to this script. (script2.sh)

`script1.sh`

```
cat <<-EOH > /lib/systemd/system/my_service.service
[Unit]
Description=My Service
StartLimitIntervalSec=600

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/opt/bin/agent --host=localhost:${PORT} --debug=${_DEBUG}'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOH
```

`script2.sh`

```
PORT=$(get_random_port)
_DEBUG=$(get_debug_value)
sudo systemctl enable my_service.service
sudo systemctl restart my_service.service
```

when VM is created, service is installed (script1.sh) runs, then later (script2.sh) runs, but I don't see PORT or _DEBUG getting updated.

Troubleshooting done:

- pass `set -a`
- print `env` and I can see PORT & _DEBUG with correct value
- pass `Environment` to systemctl service.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
StartLimitIntervalSec=600

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="PORT=${PORT}"
Environment="_DEBUG=${_DEBUG}"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/opt/bin/agent --host=localhost:${PORT} --debug=${_DEBUG}'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to overwrite the service and that works, but does not seem to be a solid solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.  Try Unix & Linux or Server Fault. That said, have you tried setting Environment=_DEBUG= PORT= in the Service section?

Comment: Variables set in a script are local to that shell (unless they're exported as environment variables), in which case subprocesses get copies of them. They are not permanent, and don't exist outside of the shell and its subprocesses.

Comment: Just Edited: I tried set -a, and Environment, no luck, should I try `export` ?

Comment: @californian Exporting the variable will not help; as I said, that only makes subprocesses inherit copies of the variable. Variables simply do not work the way you want them to. If you want some value(s) to be available to all processes, you need to do something like store them in a file.

Comment: can you promote this to answer I will try EnvironmentFile

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself and this thread is the top result.

Put short systemd tries to resolve the variables itself **before** starting the process specified under `ExecStart`. You can prevent it from doing this and treat the dollar sign literally by doubling them up (`$$`), preventing systemd from trying to evaluate them.

The man page for `systemd.service(5)` has this to share

> To pass a literal dollar sign, use "$$". Variables whose value is not known at expansion time are treated as empty strings. Note that the first
> argument (i.e. the program to execute) may not be a variable.

For more detail with examples:

If you check the status of the service after this experience the logging reveals systemd attempted to resolve the variables itself before executing the specified `ExecStart` command. It uses the `Environment=` variable in the `[Service]` section of the unit file. If it fails to determine what the variables should be they get replaced with nothing (blanks).

In the below example unit:

- An in-line Bash script is set as the `ExecStart` command. Its goal is to set and echo a variable.
- I've have also set `Environment` in the unit file for systemd to demonstrate its expansion which occurs before `ExecStart`.
- I check the results of the service run afterwards.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/test.service
[Unit]
Description=test.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=myVar=this_is_a_systemd_variable
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'myVar=MyVariable ; echo ${myVar}'

$ systemctl start test.service
$ journalctl -u test 2>/dev/null|grep bash | tail -n1
01 Jan 10:00:00 hostname bash[34]: this_is_a_systemd_variable
```

In the above example the `ExecStart` command effectively became:
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'myVar=MyVariable ; this_is_a_systemd_variable` ignoring the variable Bash set.

If we instead use `$$` for variables we intend to use as part of the in-line bash script of the `ExecStart` command, bash is able to handle its own variables as intended:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/test.service
[Unit]
Description=test.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=myVar=this_is_a_systemd_variable
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'myVar=MyVariable ; echo $${myVar}'

$ systemctl start test.service
$ journalctl -u test 2>/dev/null|grep bash | tail -n1
01 Jan 10:01:36 hostname bash[42]: MyVariable
```

Hope this helps!